# Firebase value event listener returns null for limit to last :android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, nosql

Firebase value event listener will return null value when we query the data with `limittoLast ()`
example

```
Root:
   "name":"RAJ"
```

My query is like

```
rootRef.child("name").limitToLast(10).addValueEventListenerForSingleValue {
@OverRide
public void onDataChange (DataSnapShot datasnap) {
// some code here 
 Log .d ("Data ", String.value (datasnap.getValue ());
 //the above will return null
}
}
```

But the same query with little modification

```
rootRef.child("name").addValueEventListenerForSingleValue { ...}
```

It will return the proper value "RAJ"

I didn't get what's happening behind it if I use limitToLast for the particular node to retrieve the data

The query will work if we retrieving json object

Answer (score 0):

Adding `limitToLast(N)` to a [DatabaseReference](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/DatabaseReference), as you have done in your example, yields a [Query](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/Query)  which evaluates the *children* of the reference location and returns a snapshot containing the data for not more than N children.  In your case, location `name` has no children, so the snapshot is null.

Query provides other methods for sorting and filter child data.  These are [described in the documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/lists-of-data#sorting_and_filtering_data).